# Unix script rename my file name from file_epoctimestamp to file_timestamp

Tags: shell, unix, sh, epoch

I have file name Transaction-0-0-1458049146806.txt and i want to rename this to normal timestamp like Transaction-2016-03-16?

and also in UNIX script how to convert Sun Sep 26 14:53:26 CDT 48173  into YYYY-MM-DD or YY-MM-DD

Any help?

Comment: if i do date -d@1458049146806 i am getting output as Sun Sep 26 14:53:26 CDT 48173 but i want output in YY-MM-DD

Comment: In your shell, try `man date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date -d@1458049146 "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old=Transaction-0-0-1458049146.txt

stamp=`echo $old | sed -e 's/^.*-\([0-9][0-9]*\).txt/\1/g'`
horo=`date -d @$stamp +'%Y-%m-%d'`
new="`echo $old | cut -d"-" -f1`-$horo.`echo $old | cut -d'.' -f2`"

echo $new
```

## but, it is better to use :

```
horo=`date -d @$stamp +'%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'`
```

## to avoid overwriting files created in one day